backdrop-filter not working in Firefox 131
I have updated Firefox to the latest version (131.0.3). Though the property is supported in FF 103+, on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter I'm seeing:

Both layout.css.backdrop-filter.enabled and layout.css.backdrop-filter.force-enabled are set to true. What can be wrong with the settings?

It's working fine for me (WIndows11 FF 131.0.3). What OS are you using, and do you have any settings set which might affect the implementation of this property?

Hi @AHaworth, I have already reinstalled it and it's working now. Thank you anyway.

Steps:

In Firefox type about:config
Search for backdrop
You get result like
layout.css.backdrop-filter.enabled this should be true

Note: If you are not familiar than reinstall browser.

Hi @Jignesh, as I wrote, both layout.css.backdrop-filter.enabled and layout.css.backdrop-filter.force-enabled are set to true.

Can you try with reinstall the browser? In my firefox
layout.css.backdrop-filter.force-enabled this one is false,  I have checked backdrop works fine
